# What is the Minimum brightness setting on an Acer CB280HKbmjdppr

Tags: display, brightness

I would like to buy a cheap 4k monitor. I found an Acer CB280HKbmjdppr, but I can't find any information about the minimum brightness level of the monitor.

I need to know because I'm often in darkness, and I don't want a monitor which will dazzle my eyes. I would like to know if this one is comfortable to use at night. Brightness in cd / m2 will also very helpful.

Comment: Hello! Hardware shopping recommendation requests, such as this, are off-topic for SU.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I don't ask about shopping recommendation. I just would like to know the minimum brightness level of that monitor.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing a minimum brightness spec for any monitor.  You might want to just contact Acer tech support (or sales), and see if they can tell you.

Comment: @fixer1234 I also have never seen minimum brightness in spec, but sometimes it is in test and benchmarks. I will ask Acer support, but I don't think they will answer. I know one user who can check it, but unfortunately Stack Exchange does't provide any option to tag someone or do something else.